# The type initializer threw an exception for one of my modules?

Tags: vb.net, exception, types, module, initializer

```
Module Upgradesupport
Friend RegistryFncs_definst as new registryFncs
Friend AccessApplication_definst As New Access.Application
Friend RDOrdoEngine_definst As New RDO.rdoEngine
Friend DAODBEngine_definst As New DAO.DBEngine    
end module
```

this is all the code for that module. it throws the exception when the form that uses it loads (thats when the module is called) i dont know what is causing the problem but it could be the third or fourth line.

Comment: try putting that block a `Try/Catch` to determine which line is failing

Comment: I cant add a try/catch to the module without an error (statement cant appear outside of a method body)

Comment: ack - my mistake!  get rid of the NEW on each of them, and add lines to initialize them elsewhere, in some related class's constructor maybe

Comment: Sorry im not quite following the part where im initializing them elsewhere, would it be something like DAODBEngine_definst = ... ?

Comment: yes: `DAODBEngine_definst = New DAO.DBEngine`  Hard to advise **where** to do that, in the `Sub New` of some class which uses them maybe.

Comment: i did get rid of that error with your advice thank you very much! now to struggle some more with databases...

Comment: I'll add as an answer so you can accept it and move this off the Unanswered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the declaration from creating an instance something like this:

```
Module Upgradesupport
    Friend RegistryFncs_definst as registryFncs
    Friend AccessApplication_definst As Access.Application
    Friend RDOrdoEngine_definst As RDO.rdoEngine
    Friend DAODBEngine_definst As DAO.DBEngine    
End Module
```

Removing the `New` reduces it to a declaration of assembly-wide Scope.  Then in some related class, most logically in the constructor:

```
 Public Class SomeRelatedClass
    Public Sub New
        ' initialize objects
        RegistryFncs_definst = New registryFncs
        AccessApplication_definst  = New Access.Application
        RDOrdoEngine_definst = New RDO.rdoEngine
        DAODBEngine_definst = New DAO.DBEngine  

        ' other stuff you need
    End Sub
```

**IF** your app starts from a Sub Main rather than a main form, you could do the initialization in Sub Main:

```
Public Sub Main
    ' initialize objects
    RegistryFncs_definst = New registryFncs
    AccessApplication_definst  = New Access.Application
    RDOrdoEngine_definst = New RDO.rdoEngine
    DAODBEngine_definst = New DAO.DBEngine
End Sub
```